# Add Results of Three Subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
id   item_name_1   quantity 1   item_name_2   quantity_2   item_name_3   quantity_3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Apple         2            Pear          3            Orange        5
2    Pear          1            Apple         4
3    Orange        6
4    Apple         1            Pear          2            Orange        3
```

I want this result:

```
item     total
--------------
Apple    7
Pear     6
Orange   14
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT

(SELECT item_name_1, SUM(quantity_1) AS count FROM table1
GROUP BY item_name_1) AS item,

(SELECT item_name_2, SUM(quantity_2) AS count FROM table1
GROUP BY item_name_2) AS item,

(SELECT item_name_3, SUM(quantity_3) AS count FROM table1
GROUP BY item_name_3) AS item,

SUM(count) AS total
FROM table1
GROUP BY item;
```

Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Any suggestions?

Comment: For starters, your database isn't properly normalized.  Is this your database, or someone else's?

Comment: It's my database. I will work on normalizing it. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting two columns in your sub-queries when there can only be one column.

Something like this will get you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT item_name, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
FROM
(SELECT item_name_1 AS item_name, SUM(quantity_1) AS quantity
FROM table1
GROUP BY item_name_1

UNION ALL

SELECT item_name_2 AS item_name, SUM(quantity_2) AS quantity
FROM table1
GROUP BY item_name_2

UNION ALL

SELECT item_name_3 AS item_name, SUM(quantity_3) AS quantity
FROM table1
GROUP BY item_name_3) AS ABB1
GROUP BY item_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like this.

```
select t.item_name_1, s1+s2+s3

from
(
select * From
(    
select sum(quantity_1) as s1, item_name_1
from
table1
group by item_name_1
) t1

full outer join 

(    
select sum(quantity_2) as s2, item_name_2
from
table1
group by item_name_2
) t2 on t1.item_name_1 = t2.item_name_2

full outer join 

(    
select sum(quantity_3) as s3, item_name_3
from
table1
group by item_name_3
) t3 on t2.item_name_2 = t3.item_name_3

) t
```